# Update customer prestashop doesn't work

Tags: php, xml, prestashop

I am trying to update a customer in prestashop using a webservice. The webservice is written in PHP. Now the problem is that i can't update the customer using the code examples because he keeps giving me the same error

```
This call to PrestaShop Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 404. That means: Not Found.
```

But I can get the data from the website but when I want to change it it gives the error.

The strange thing is that when i use the code to locally update the user it does work.

the code below :

```
define('DEBUG', false);
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'www.Myshop.com');
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', 'HERE IS NORMALLY THE CORRECT AUTH_KEY ');
require_once('PSWebServiceLibrary.php');

// Here we use the WebService to get the schema of "customers" resource

// First : We always get the customer's list or a specific one
try
{
    $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
    $opt = array('resource' => 'customers');
    if (isset($_GET['id']))
        $opt['id'] = $_GET['id'];
    $xml = $webService->get($opt);
    // Here we get the elements from children of customer markup which is children of prestashop root markup
    $resources = $xml->children()->children();
}
catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $e)
{
    // Here we are dealing with errors
    $trace = $e->getTrace();
    if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 404) echo 'Bad ID';
    else if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 401) echo 'Bad auth key';
    else echo 'Other error<br />'.$e->getMessage();
}
// Second : We update the data and send it to the web service
if (isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_POST['id'])) // Here we check id cause in every resource there's an id
{
    // Here we have XML before update, lets update XML with new values
    foreach ($resources as $nodeKey => $node)
    {

        $resources->$nodeKey = $_POST[$nodeKey];


    }
    // And call the web service
    try
    {
        $opt = array('resource' => 'customers');
        $opt['id'] = $_GET[ 'id' ];
        $opt['putXml'] = $xml->children()->asXML();
        $xml =$webService->edit($opt) ;

        // if WebService don't throw an exception the action worked well and we don't show the following message
        echo "Successfully updated.";
    }
    catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex)
    {
        // Here we are dealing with errors
        echo "testy";
        $trace = $ex->getTrace();
        if ($trace[1]['args'][0] == 404) echo 'Bad ID';
        else if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 401) echo 'Bad auth key';
        else echo 'Other error<br />'.$ex->getMessage();
    }
}
// UI
// We set the Title
echo '<h1>Customer\'s ';
if (isset($_GET['id'])) echo 'Update';
else echo 'List';
echo '</h1>';
// We set a link to go back to list if we are in customer's details
if (isset($_GET['id']))
    echo '<a href="?">Return to the list</a>';
if (isset($_GET['id']))
    echo '<form method="POST" action="?id='.$_GET['id'].'">';
echo '<table border="5">';
if (isset($resources))
{
echo '<tr>';
if (!isset($_GET['id']))
{
    //Show list of customers
    echo '<th>Id</th><th>More</th></tr>';
    foreach ($resources as $resource)
    {
        echo '<td>'.$resource->attributes().'</td><td>'.
        '<a href="?id='.$resource->attributes().'">Update</a>&nbsp;'.
        '</td></tr>';
    }
}
else
{
    //Show customer form
    echo '</tr>';
    foreach ($resources as $key => $resource)
    {
        echo '<tr><th>'.$key.'</th><td>';
        echo '<input type="text" name="'.$key.'" value="'.$resource.'"/>';
        echo '</td></tr>';
    }
}
}
echo '</table><br/>';
if (isset($_GET['id']))
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Update"></form>';
?>
</body></html>
```

Hope that somebody can help me.

Comment: Hello. Try to activate DEBUG MODE in your webservices shop to have more error details. Check POST permission in your hosting. Good luck.

Comment: First of all thanks for looking at my problem. When I activated my debug mode I didn't see anything strange but when I checked my permissions on the hosting I could see the problem. Thanks for the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not in my code but in my .htaccess file.

when I added this code below i didn't have errors and could update the data

```
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE HEAD OPTIONS>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Limit>
<LimitExcept GET POST PUT DELETE HEAD OPTIONS>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
```

Thanks everybody for the support